# Same method, different argument types, implemented in a single go

Tags: scala

I have a (Java) class with operations like this:

```
abstract class Holder {
    def set(i: Int): Unit
    def set(s: String): Unit
    def set(b: Boolean): Unit
    ...
}
```

Essentially, the all perform the same task, but just take different argument types. I would love to create a generic Accessor[T] that performs something like this:

```
class Accessor[T](holder: Holder) { 
    def set(value: T) { holder.set(value) }
}
```

... but that gives:

```
<console>:16: error: overloaded method value set with alternatives:
  (s: String)Unit <and>
  (i: Int)Unit
  (b: Boolean)Unit
 cannot be applied to (T)
       def set(value: T) { holder.set(value) }
```

Is there any way out?

Comment: I don't think you've specified the problem fully enough.  Otherwise, using `set(a: Any): Unit` would work.  Can you give an example of what all those `set` statements actually would end up doing in a subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at the results gathered so far, there are a couple of solutions suggested:

- Use pattern matching (leads to fragmentation of the different strategies of dealing with the different parameter types)
- Use reflection (to expensive for something that ideally should be *super fast*)
- ... and adding the one that I eventually ended up implementing: write an adapter per type of parameter.

To be a little more precise, the whole exercise was about writing a wrapper around Kyoto Cabinet. Kyoto Cabinet has methods for associating byte array keys with byte array values and String keys with String values. And then it basically replicates most of the operations for dealing with keys and values for both byte array as well as Strings.

In order to create a Map wrapper around Kyoto Cabinet's DB class, I defined a trait TypedDBOperations[T], with T being the type of parameter, and had it implemented twice. If I now construct a Map[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]], an implicit conversion will automatically assign it the proper instane of TypedDBOperations, calling the Array[Byte] based operations of the DB class.

This is the trait that I have been talking about:

```
trait TypedDBOperations[K,V] {
  def get(db: DB, key: K): V
  def set(db: DB, key: K, value: V): Boolean
  def remove(db: DB, key: K): Boolean
  def get(cursor: Cursor): (K, V)
}
```

And these are the implementations for both type of key value combinations:

```
  implicit object StringDBOperations extends TypedDBOperations[String] {
    def get(cursor: Cursor) = {
      val Array(a, b) = cursor.get_str(false)
      (a, b)
    }
    def remove(db: DB, key: String) = db.remove(key)
    def set(db: DB, key: String, value: String) = db.set(key, value)
    def get(db: DB, key: String) = db.get(key)
  }

  implicit object ByteArrayOperations extends TypedDBOperations[Array[Byte]] {
    def get(cursor: Cursor) = {
      val Array(a, b) = cursor.get(false)
      (a, b)
    }
    def remove(db: DB, key: Array[Byte]) = db.remove(key)
    def set(db: DB, key: Array[Byte], value: Array[Byte]) = db.set(key, value)
    def get(db: DB, key: Array[Byte]) = db.get(key)
  }
```

Not the most satisfying solution ever, but it gets the job done. Again, note there still is quite a bit of duplication, but it seems there's no way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

Use reflection.

```
class Setter(obj: AnyRef) {
  val clazz = obj.getClass
  def set[T : Manifest](v: T): Boolean = try {
      val paramType = manifest[T].erasure
      val method = clazz.getMethod("set", paramType)
      method.invoke(obj, v.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
      true
  } catch {
      case ex => false
  }
}

val holder = ..
val setter = new Setter(holder)
setter.set(5) // returns true
setter.set(1.0) // double not accepted, returns false
```

There was an experimental shortcut for that in Scala, but it got removed before 2.8.0 was released.

Comment: Voting up because I didn't know about that feature in the version leading up to 2.8.0.

Answer (score 2):

I think matching should work nicely

```
def set(value: T) {
    value match {
         case s: String => holder.set(s)
         case i: Int => holder.set(i)
         case b: Boolean => holder.set(b)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, that could work, but there are more operations on 'Holder' that are type specific, and find myself continuously writing the same code over and over again, where in fact there is no difference in the signature of the operation other than the type.

Comment: I absolutely see your point. I guess one could create a reflection hack, doing the type casting once and then calling the apropriate method using reflection. But this of course is reflection ...

Comment: If you have lots of code in Holder (all the "redundant" methods), then you'll need lots of code to interface to it.

Comment: The problem is that I can't change Holder. I need to wrap it in a sensible way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your use case, but one thing that you might try doing--if performance is not of utmost importance--is creating a wrapper class that converts to a universal form for you, and then have all your methods take that wrapper class (with appropriate implicit conversions in place).  For example:

```
class Wrap(val data: String)
implicit def wrapString(s: String) = new Wrap(s)
implicit def wrapBoolean(b: Boolean) = if (b) new Wrap("T") else new Wrap("F")
implicit def wrapLong(l: Long) = new Wrap(l.toString+"L")

class User {
  private[this] var myData = ""
  def set(w: Wrap) { println("Setting to "+w.data); myData = w.data }
}

val u = new User
u.set(true)
u.set(50L)
u.set(50)     // Int gets upconverted to Long for free, so this works
u.set("Fish")
// u.set(3.14159)  // This is a type mismatch
```

This is a little bit like taking an `Any` except that you can restrict the types however you like and specify the conversion into whatever universal representation you have in mind.  However, if there does not exist a universal form, then I'm not sure in what sense that you mean the code is doing the same thing each time.  (Maybe you mean that you can conceive of a macro (or another program) that would generate the code automatically--Scala doesn't have that support built in, but you can of course write a Scala program that produces Scala code.)